# Fish Shell function that works with piped input or with argument based input

Tags: fish

I'm trying to create a fish shell function that will trim new lines from the input and then copy the input to the clipboard.

How can I write this function so that it will;

- Process pipeline input (this works now)
- Process first argument as if it were input piped to the function
- Exit immediately in the case that no value is provided via argument or pipeline, right now `tr` will not exit without some value being passed in the pipeline

Code:

```
function copy --description 'Trim new lines and copy to clipboard'
    tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Update that handles newlines better:

```
function copy --description 'Trim new lines and copy to clipboard'
  cat $argv ^/dev/null | while read -l line
    set argv $argv $line
  end

  test -z "$argv"; and return

  for i in $argv
    echo -n $i
  end | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
end
```

This one was quite a challenge, but with a little bit of trickery it was possible. This function works as you described plus one caveat, if you write `copy` without any args then it will wait for your input indefinitely.

If you don't care for multiline copying you could remove the `| tr -d '\n'` before `read` and then `copy` would also work. Because read is terminated by newline. So then it would automatically just accept up to the first newline, for example `copy\nme` would copy just `copy`.

Code:

```
function copy --description 'Trim new lines and copy to clipboard'
  cat $argv ^/dev/null | tr -d '\n' | read -l input

  set -ql input; or set -l input $argv

  if test -n "$input"
    echo $input | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
  end
end
```

Example:

```
➤ echo copy\nme | copy
Clipboard: copyme

➤ copy copy\nyou
Clipboard: copyyou

➤ echo | copy
Clipboard: copyyou

➤ copy
(Waiting for command indefinitely...)
```

Comment: plese replace "^/dev/null" with "2>/dev/null" to make it work